# controlling whether upload is attached to post or not

Tags: uploads, attachments, media, media-library

I'm using the new (3.5+) media upload API to open a media modal dialog from a post meta box, and select a file from the media library (as per https://github.com/thomasgriffin/New-Media-Image-Uploader).

I need to control whether or not files uploaded through this dialog are attached to the current post or not. I'm looking through media-views.js and can't see anything to control this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [this post by Mike Jolley](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) (see 'Passing data to the uploader script').